# Obj-C, Instance variable used while 'self' is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init...]'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, analyzer

I know I asked a similar question to this not long ago, but I'm still a little unsure about it. The same sort of thing happens in several places.

Instance variable used while 'self' is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init...]'

A

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
  if (![super init]) return nil;
  red = [decoder decodeFloatForKey:kRedKey];  //occurs here
  green = [decoder decodeFloatForKey:kGreenKey];
  blue = [decoder decodeFloatForKey:kBlueKey];
  return self;
}
```

B

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame title:(NSString*)str sideUp:(BOOL)up{

    if(![super initWithFrame:frame]) return nil;

    int y;
    UIImage *img;

    if(up){
        img = [UIImage imageNamedTK:@"TapkuLibrary.bundle/Images/graph/popup"];
        y = 5;
    }else{
        img = [UIImage imageNamedTK:@"TapkuLibrary.bundle/Images/graph/popdown"];
        y = 14;
    }

    background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img]; // occurs here
```

C

```
 - (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if(![super initWithFrame:frame]) return nil;

    UILabel *titleBackground = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
            CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 40)] autorelease];
    titleBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self addSubview:titleBackground];

    titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; // occurs here
```

For block A, is this correct

```
self = [self init]; 
if( self != nil )
{
```

And B & C

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
   super = [super initWithFrame:frame]
    if(super != nil)
   {
```

Comment: is this a question? and if so, what ***is*** the question?

Comment: if you write subclass, use super

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generally, you're supposed to write:

```
self = [super init...];  // Potentially change "self"
if (self) {
    something = x;
    another = y;
}
return self;
```

This is because `init` may not return the original `self` value in some cases.

Comment: Thanks for your clear and none technical answer... why `self =[super` and not `self = [self` ?

Comment: You can use `self = [self init...]` if the version of `init...` you'll be calling eventually does the `[super init...]` call, and this may be the thing to do in some cases.  (In fact, it's pretty much mandatory if your `init` is in a category on a library class.) But you need to be sure that the `super` version gets called eventually, or your object will be incomplete.