# How to fix "instance variable while 'self'"

Tags: objective-c

How to fix this analysis issue:

[image]

CODE

```
if(![super initWithFrame:CGRectZero]){
    return nil;
}

firstOfPrev = -1;
marks = markArray;
monthDate = date;
startOnSunday = sunday;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obj-C, Instance variable used while 'self' is not set to the result of '\[(super or self) init...\]'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111549/obj-c-instance-variable-used-while-self-is-not-set-to-the-result-of-super)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're never assigning the result of the super initializer call to self. I believe this is what you want:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (!(self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // do stuff

    return self;
}
```

However, this may be more clear if you write out your initializers like this:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        // do stuff
    }

    return self;
}
```